# Can a dictionary (python) like this? not string but span (from spaCy)?

Tags: python, html, dictionary, spacy

I have a question about the dictionary:

Can we **create a dictionary like dict_1**?

```
dict_1 = {Lily: [20], Tom: [21, 22]}
dict_2 = {'Lily': [20], 'Tom': [21, 22]}
```

I had only seen a dictionary like dict_2, but now, I got one like dict_1. In my dict_1, `Lily` is actually a type of .span (in spaCy). I cannot use `print(dict_1['Lily'])` or `print(dict_1[Lily])` to print `20`, it always return an error:

```
print(dict_1['Lily'])
KeyError:XXX 
(I understand this error)

or 
print(dict_1[Lily])
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
(I do not understand this error)
```

**Question**:

How can I print the value of key `Lily` in dict_1? (i.e. `20`)

Thanks!

Comment: `print(dict_1[Lily])` is perfectly valid syntax. If you have some some that caused this error, please provide the minimal code that reproduces it. And check the line above for unclosed brackets/... Note that `Lily` must be an existing variable, but that wouldn't cause a syntax error if it isn't.

Comment: thanks, as I have mentioned, I got it by combining two lists, and the items in each list are .span type (from spaCy)

Comment: Please show us some code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Thanks @Thierry Lathuille, if the `Lily` is a .span type in dict_1, then, is it possible to print its value? (i.e., `20`)

Comment: Dictionary keys have to he "hashable", only a few types are.

Comment: The keys of your `dict` are of type ".span spaCy" which when printed show up as plaint text...  check with `type` while iterating over `.keys(). You'll have to either "ask" the dictionary using the "correct" object types or make sure you have strings as keys. Try (real) debugging to better understand what you have there

Comment: thanks a lot, I have  just updated the code @Thierry Lathuille

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python, you cannot generate a dictionary with variable that are not defined.

```
dict_1 = {Lily: [20], Tom: [21, 22]} # this will not work.
```

but if you set variables to a string or other, then it can work as below:

```
Lily = "Lily"
Tom = "Tom"

dict_1 = {Lily: [20], Tom: [21, 22]} # this works!
```

Comment: thanks a lot, I have  just updated the code

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everyone's comment and answer, I got one way to print a specific key or/and value even they are `type <class 'spacy.tokens.span.Span'>`.
Maybe this can be a hint for anyone else who also has this problem:)

```
key = list(dict_1)[0]
value = list(dict_1.values())[0]
print(key) #Lily
print(value)#20

key1 = list(dict_1)[1]
value1 = list(dict_1.values())[1][0]
print(key1) #Tom
print(value1)#21
```